# Select Query Optimization :: Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I want to optimize the below DB selection query

```
select * from
    table_name 
 where
    (title=? and grade =?)
 or
    (title=? and debt =? and grade =?)
 or
     (prog=? and title = ? and debt =?)
```

Comment: Adding an index on `title` might help.

Comment: Thanks Tim, i have already added index for title and debt..

Comment: May we know something about the data?  How unique are the values in the 4 column appearing in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Hi Tim, kind of transactional , duplicacy of data may come..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use case below way as alternative

```
select * from
    table_name 
 where
     1 = case
           when title=? and grade =? then 1
           when title=? and debt =? and grade =? then 1
           when prog=? and title = ? and debt =? then 1
        else 0
     end
```

Just give a try and make sure all are indexed.

Comment: Thanks, it is working and will update the efficiency soon